# Correct way to include constant external force in virial and pressure calculation

Tags: classical-mechanics, simulations, molecular-dynamics

Halo,

given a simulation cell with N particles where particles interact only with bond and pair potentials and periodic boundary conditions (minimum image convention) are used.

On a subgroup of particles a constant (or non-constant) external force is applied.

What is the correct way to include this force in calculation of virial terms and therefore pressure.

Does the external force contribute to the virial, at all?
Or do only interatomic interactions like bond and pair potentials contribute?

Following standard literature one finds for the pressure
$$
p  =  \frac{ 2\left\langle E_{kin} \right\rangle }{3V} + \frac{ 1 }{ 3V } \left\langle \sum_{i} {\mathbf f}_{i}  {\mathbf r}_{i} \right\rangle
$$
where $E_{kin}$ is the kinetic Energy, $V$ the Volume, ${\mathbf f}_{i}$ the toal force acting on particle $i$ and ${\mathbf r}_{i}$ the position of particle $i$. This reduces to
$$
p  =  \frac{ 2\left\langle E_{kin} \right\rangle }{3V} + \frac{ 1 }{ 3V } \left\langle \sum_{i<j} {\mathbf f}_{ij}  {\mathbf r}_{ij} \right\rangle
$$
for pure pair potentials. Where ${\mathbf r}_{ij}={\mathbf r}_{j}-{\mathbf r}_{i}$ and ${\mathbf f}_{ij}$ is the force acting on particle $i$ due to particle $j$.
Therefore I would assume that I simply have to add the external force to the virial, like this
$$
p  =  \frac{ 2\left\langle E_{kin} \right\rangle }{3V} + \frac{ 1 }{ 3V } \left\langle \sum_{i<j} {\mathbf f}_{ij}  {\mathbf r}_{ij} +  \sum_{i} {\mathbf f}_{i}^{ext}  {\mathbf r}_{i} \right\rangle
$$
Where ${\mathbf f}_{i}^{ext}$ is the external force acting on particle $i$.
But I've seen that ${\mathbf f}_{i}^{ext}$ is simply omitted in some popular ready to use md packages. Now I'm not sure what to do.

Thank's in advance for help!